# python PIL image.getdata() returns data returns more data than is expected

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

the following:

```
image = Image.open(name, 'r')
data = np.array(image.getdata())
data.reshape(image.size)
```

returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr/colorviewer/main.py", line 207, in <module>
    print(getPalette())
  File "/home/usr/colorviewer/main.py", line 152, in getPalette
    data.reshape(image.size)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 921600 into shape (640,480)
```

why does it say the array size is 921600 instead of 307200 as the size would suggest, and how might the image data be reshaped into its normal resolution?

Comment: every pixel uses three values `R,G,B` and `640*480*3` gives `921600` bytes. And image can be transparent then it may have `640*480*4` bytes. So you need reshape into `(640,480,3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every pixel uses three values `R,G,B` so you have `640*480*3` which gives `921600` bytes.

So you need reshape into `(640,480,3)`. And it needs `*` to unpack `size`.

```
data.reshape(*image.size, 3)
```

If image can be transparent then it may have `640*480*4` bytes. And it can be safer to reshape `(640,480,-1)` and it should automatically ise `3` or `4`

```
data.reshape(*image.size, -1)
```

---

Or you should skip `.getdata()` and you get already reshaped array

```
data = np.array(image)
```